# Computing elementary symmetric polynomials of degree $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-functions

My question is related to page 4 of [http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2020/REUPapers/Graham.pdf](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2020/REUPapers/Graham.pdf)

Let $e_j=\sum \limits_{1\leq i_1<...<i_j \leq n}x_{i_1}\dots x_{i_j}$ be the elementary symmetric polynomials.

It's $e_0=1$ and $e_\lambda=e_\lambda{_{1}}\dots e_\lambda{_n}$ for a partition $\lambda$.

I want to compute all polynomials of the form $e_\lambda$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3]^{S_3}$ which are of degree $3$.

My way was:

It's $|\lambda|=3$, so the partitions are $\lambda=(3), \lambda=(2,1)$ and $\lambda=(1,1,1)$.

Then I computed it for $\lambda=(3)$ and I got:

$e_\lambda=e_3=x_1x_2x_3$

Where is my mistake here?

The solution says it's $e_3=x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3$.

How was it computed?

Edit: Wikipedia also says it's $e_3(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1x_2x_3$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Comment: $p_3 = m_3 = x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3$ is not an elementary symmetric polynomial.

Comment: In the notes you refer to, he uses $m_\lambda$ (monomial symmetric polynomial) which is not the same as elementary symmetric polynomials. In elementary symmetric polynomials $e_k$ we don't allow repetitions in the subindex.

Comment: @sakamoto: the notes also contain the (false) statement $e_3 = x_1^3 + \ldots$ -- it's just an error on the author's part.

Comment: (Not really terribly surprising given that it's an REU paper.  Seems like a poor choice of a source to learn from!)

Answer (score 1):

You’re totally fine, the mistake was on the part of the author. Indexing by integers you attain

\begin{align}
e_{1}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) &= x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}, \\
e_{2}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) &= x_{1}x_{2} + x_{1}x_{3} + x_{2}x_{3}, \\
e_{3}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) &= x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}.
\end{align}

Then to get your elementary symmetric polynomials indexed by partitions, you just start multiplying

\begin{align}
e_{(3)}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) &= x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}, \\
e_{(2,1)}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) &= x_{1}^{2}x_{2} + x_{1}^{2}x_{3} + x_{1}x_{2}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}x_{3} + x_{1}x_{3}^{2} + x_{2}x_{3}^{2} + 3x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}, \\
e_{(1,1,1)}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) &= x_{1}^{3} + x_{2}^{3} + x_{3}^{3} + 3(x_{1}^{2}x_{2} + x_{1}^{2}x_{3} + x_{1}x_{2}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}x_{3} + x_{1}x_{3}^{2} + x_{2}x_{3}^{2}) + 6x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}.
\end{align}

Although I'm not sure how useful this exercise is. In general, I prefer to just leave these in the form

\begin{equation}
e_{(7,4^{3},2,1^{4})} = e_{7}e_{4}^{3}e_{2}e_{1}^{4}.
\end{equation}